# Grails 3.0.8 PayPal:button not shown

Tags: grails, paypal

I try to add a PayPal button in my grails 3 app.
I haven't found any howto's for grails 3 so I tried one for grails 2
(https://grails.org/wiki/PayPal%20Plugin).

Step 1) Install the plugin.
In grails 2:

```
grails install-plugin paypal
```

This is not working in grails 3. However there is an install command, but this doesn't accept paypal as parameter.
So I added

```
dependencies {
    .
    .
    .
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-core:1.6.9'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:buttonmanagersdk:2.6.106'
}
```

to my build.gradle.
Is this the wrong way to add the paypal plugin ?

Step 2) configure constants.
In grails 2 edit Config.groovy:

```
environments {
    production {
        grails.paypal.server = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
        grails.paypal.email = "example@business.com"
        grails.serverURL = "http://www.grails.org"      
     }
     development {
         grails.paypal.server = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
         grails.paypal.email = "testpp_1211202427_biz@g2one.com"
         grails.serverURL = "http://812.99.101.131"             
   }
}
```

Config.groovy is not used in Grails 3 so I added the following to application.yml

```
environments:
    development:
        grails.paypal.server : https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
        grails.paypal.email : example@business.com
        grails.serverURL : http://www.grails.org
```

Do i have to configure this elsewhere ?

Step 3) Create the PayPal button.
This should be the same in grails 2 and 3
add:

```
<paypal:button 
itemName="name"
itemNumber="theNumber"
transactionId="theTransactionId"
amount="1337,00"
discountAmount="0"
buyerId="theId"
/>
```

To the gsp file.
Do i have to include the paypal taglib (it's not included in the example) ?

When I test my app I got

```
<paypal:button 
itemName="name"
itemNumber="theNumber"
transactionId="theTransactionId"
amount="1337,00"
discountAmount="0"
buyerId="theId"
/>
```

in my html.

What do I have to do to get my PayPal button working ?

regards Kai

Comment: You can't force a Grails 2 plugin to work on Grails 3. The two plugins I found are abandoned and don't work with any recent version of Grails. If you find the source code, maybe you can upgrade it to Grails 3.

Comment: @daskai0815 Did you find solution for this problem? I' struggling for the same. Are there any ways to integrate paypal plugin with Grails 3?